# Is there a way to store an actual database scheme close to chagelogs?

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I have configured the liquibase migration for my Spring Boot application. Now I have a chagelog folder with all changes and I'd like to have a file with current database scheme because it's convenient. Does liquibase have best practices for storing actual db scheme in Spring Boot project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is confusing. When you say "a file with current database scheme", are you referring to the actual database with data (such as a SQLite file) or a script to create the database initial state?

**If what you want is the actual database**, this is not a liquibase concern. You could certainly put the database file in the same folder as the scripts, but that would not make a lot of sense to me. The liquibase scripts should be considered part of your source code, the database is execution environment specific and probably belongs elsewhere.

**If you want a script for the initial state**, that is absolutely something you can do with liquibase. The command you want is [generateChangeLog](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html). This will analyse your existing database and generate a changelog to recreate it. You would then refer to it as the first changelog to execute in your scripts.

```
 java -jar liquibase.jar 
         --classpath=sqlitejdbc-v<version>.jar 
         --driver=org.sqlite.JDBC 
         --url="jdbc:sqlite:exampledb.sqlite" 
         --changeLogFile=db.changelog.initial-state.xml 
         generateChangeLog
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <include file="db.changelog.initial-state.xml" />

    <changeSet author="captain" id="diff1">
        do some stuff
    </changeset>
    <changeSet author="captain" id="diff2">
        do some more stuff
    </changeset>
    ...
```